# Android Studio - How to disable the scrolling code preview overlay?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, ide

In Android Studio (and IntelliJ IDEA), when you hover your cursor in the scrollbar area of the editing window, the cursor changes to a pointing hand and displays a 10-line preview of the code in that location in the file.  Here's a screenshot:

[image]

As you move your cursor up and down that scrollbar area, the code preview overlay shifts with it.  I've dug through the preferences and searched online, but I can't figure out how to turn off this feature.  Does anyone know what this is called and how to disable it?

Comment: Thanks for asking!  It bogs the IDE down when all I want to do is jump to another point in the file.

Comment: I am sure most developers find this annoying and I'm surprised that it isn't turned off by default.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's called the "code lens" and it's configurable in:

```
Editor -> General -> Appearance
```

In some versions, it's called "editor preview tooltip" instead of "code lens."

[image]

Also can be disabled by right-clicking on the scroll bar area.

Comment: Thanks, Dave.  On my versions of both IDEs (Mac - Android Studio 1.1, IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE), it's called "editor preview tooltip" instead of "code lens."  I've edited your answer to include this variation.

Comment: in my case, I had to restart the AS after applying your solution, +1 for the solution

Answer (score 2):

If you right click on the scroll bar you can very easily disable it.

Uncheck 'Show code lens on scrollbar hover' and it'll disable it. Alternatively you can disable from preferences using that as a search filter.

Comment: This works, too.  And now I know that you can right-click on the scrollbar!